# jQuery show within page fails unless alert is added (or debug)

Tags: jquery

I am sure this is a timing issue of some sort but I can't get to the root of it.
Some background
We have a web app which loads and changes data via javascript (no ajax calls, all data is local to the page).
We are working on the mobile version and of course it takes longer to render the pages so we are trying to add a "loading, please wait" image while the stuff renders behind the scenes.
I have the div element added and it works fine on initial page load but when the user changes screens the loading div does not show up unless I either put in an alert right after the show or debug things stepping through.

Here is part of the code

```
function showSpinner() {
   // if already being shown why show again
   if (!spinnerOn)
   {
      $("#loading").show();
      spinnerOn = true;
      //alert("loading div should be visible");
   }
}

function closeSpinner() {
    spinnerOn = false;
    $("#loading").hide();
}
```

If I put that alert back in the showSpinner function div shows up, if not it doesn't.

The function is called as part of another function (triggered by an onClick)

```
showSpinner();
navObj.setCurrTabID(tabID);
tabObj = navObj.getCurrTabObjects();
$.each(tabObj, function (index) {
    currID = "#" + index;
    if (index == tabID) {
       $(currID).addClass("active");
       $(currID).removeClass("inactive");
    }
    else {
       $(currID).addClass("inactive");
       $(currID).removeClass("active");
    }
});

displayMainDataSection(NO_CHANGE);
```

Here is the displayMainDataSection (there is a lot of other code as well)

```
function displayMainDataSection(initLevel)
{

    $("#notes-table").hide();
    $("#bubbleCaps").hide();
    $("#equiGraph-middle").hide();
    $("#pieSection").hide();
    $("#descBox").hide();
    $("#raceSection").hide();
    $("#horseNotesDisplay").hide();
    $("#gridDesc").empty();
    $("#horseLegend").hide();
    $("#playerChoices").hide();
    $("#graphChoices").hide();
    $("#pieButtonSetDiv").hide();
    $("#spdButtonSetDiv").hide();
    $("#statsTableReg").empty();
    $("#raceListDiv").hide();

    hideMessages();
    hideBigOrSmallDivs();
    resetMargins();
    if (hammer) {
        setHammer();
    }



    switch (navObj.currScreen) {
         case 'notes':
            // Display the NOTES data screen
            clearDataSectionDivs("");
            displayNotesScreen();
            $("#notes-table").show();
            break;
       case 'raceSummary':
            // Display the Race Summary Screen
            if (!isSmallScreen) {
                $("#equiGraph-middle").show();
                $("#gridDesc").html(raceListDescText);
            }
            else {
                // remove the header bottom margin for the the race list and the horse list
                $(".equiGraph-model").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
            }
            showRegTableDiv();
            displayRaceSumMiddleSection();
            // show the Static table ("Reg"), not one controlled by a "show grid" button
            displayTableTitleLine("Reg");
            displayTableSection(navObj.getDefaultTableID(), "Reg");
            break;
       case 'bubbleCap':
            // Display the Bubble Capper Screen
            $("#bubbleCaps").show();
            showGridTableDiv();
            displayMiddleSection();
            clearDataSectionDivs();
            displayTableTitleLine("");
            displayTableSection(navObj.getDefaultTableID(), "");
            displayBubbleGraphs(initLevel, navObj.getDefaultBubCapDisplay());
            break;
       case 'speed':
            // Display the Speed/Class Screen
            showGridTableDiv();
            displayMiddleSection();
            $("#gridDesc").html(raceGraphDescText);
            displayTableTitleLine("");
            displayTableSection(navObj.getDefaultTableID(), "");
            changeSpdClsGraphType(navObj.getDefaultSpdClsGraph());
            //showGridDialog();
            break;
       case 'playerPie':
            // Display the Player Pie Screen
            showGridTableDiv();
            displayMiddleSection();
            $("#pieSection").show();
            changePieChartSection(navObj.getDefaultGraphCol(), navObj.getDefaultGraphType());
            displayTableTitleLine("");
            displayTableSection(navObj.getDefaultTableID());
            break;
      default:  //signals
            showRegTableDiv();
            displayMiddleSection();
            // show the Static table, not one controlled by "show grid" button
            displayTableSection(navObj.getDefaultTableID(), "Reg");
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

It actually can be called from a couple of spots and then the end of displayMainDataSection calls the closeSpinner function to hide the div again.

Any thoughts on why the div doesn't show up?

Comment: can you post the contents of displayMainDataSection()?

Comment: Where is `#loading` in relation to the rest of your elements?  Is its parent element in any way refreshed by the `display...Section` function?  Also, you said that it calls the `closeSpinner` method in the `display...Section` function; I don't see it.  And lastly, I'll throw out a hypothesis: until the currently executing JS thread is interrupted, it might queue up the changes that the code block caused. So if `.show` happens, then another function is called which does some things and then a `.close` is triggered, you might not ever see it!  All that JS executed back-to-back-to-back.

Comment: To add more to the above hypothesis.  The `alert` interrupts the current thread, which allows it to show up.  Try: `setTimeout(function() { displayMainDataSection(NO_CHANGE); }, 30);` and work that `30` down to `0` and see if it flickers.  `setTimeout` interrupts execution so you might actually see it show up.  Not that it's the UX you want, but it should at least help confirm or reject my hypothesis.

Comment: The close got moved in between when I first asked and finally asked (still trying to fix the @%(&()_ thing :-)

Comment: This got me working (although now of course marketing wants a setTimeout on the show which breaks everything again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not uncommon with synchronous code to see only the nett state of the DOM, on completion, not intermediate states.

If an alert causes the spinner to show, then so should a `setTimeout(`), something like this :

```
showSpinner();
setTimeout(function() {
    navObj.setCurrTabID(tabID);
    var tabObj = navObj.getCurrTabObjects();
    clss = ["inactive", "active"];
    $.each(tabObj, function(index) {
        $("#" + index).addClass(clss[+(index == tabID)]).removeClass(clss[+(index !== tabID)]);
    });
    displayMainDataSection(NO_CHANGE);
}, 0);
```

If it still doesn't show, then try increasing the timeout delay to eg. 100.