# Spinner bound to ajax call will not display unless I put an alert in the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote a simple method that adds a spinner to the main body of an html page and binds the  event to an ajaxstart method then removes it on the ajaxstop.

```
StartAjaxCallSpinner = function (spinnerObj) {    
    var $bod = $("Body");
    if ($('#bgSpinnerDiv')[0] == undefined && $('#spinnerHolder')[0] == undefined) {
        $bod.append("<div id='spinnerHolder' style='display:none;'></div><div id='bgSpinnerDiv'></div>");
    }

    $('#spinnerHolder')
            .hide()  
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $('#bgSpinnerDiv').css({ 'background-color': 'black',
                    'height': '100%',
                    'left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '0.7',
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '0px',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'z-index': '1000001'
                });
                $(this).css({ 'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '50%',
                    'left': '50%',
                    'width': '130px',
                    'height': '130px',
                    'margin-top': '-65px',
                    'margin-left': '-65px',
                    'z-index': '1000002',
                    'display': 'block',
                    'border': '1px solid black',
                    'border-radius': '5px',
                    'background': " white url('" + spinnerObj.SpinnerUri + "') no-repeat center center"
                });
                $(this).show();
                //alert('test');
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#bgSpinnerDiv').removeAttr("style").unbind('ajaxStart', UnBindAjaxStop($('#bgSpinnerDiv')));
                $(this).removeAttr("style").unbind('ajaxStart', UnBindAjaxStop(this));
            });
};

UnBindAjaxStop = function (me) {
    $(me).unbind('ajaxStop');
};
```

I call the method before an ajax call and pass it an object with the uri of the spinner gif, but the spinner and background do not display unless I have an alert. I have tried adding a `setTimeout()function{/*do some code*/},1000)` in various places, but that did not seems to help.

I saw a similar issue in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948037/jquery-show-within-page-fails-unless-alert-is-added-or-debug) but the setTimeout does not seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: just a wild guess since you didn't include your ajax code, but... remove `async: false` from your ajax request.

Comment: I have to admit, this is quite the script you have here...Why not just create a simple ajax function and in the function trigger the spinner show on start and then hide on complete?

Comment: @KevinB removing the 'async: false, ' works, nice call!

Comment: @VIDesignz I don't want to have to do that for every ajax call instance I have, I also plan on making this method more customize-able where I pass in a more robust object with different parameters for different uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your ajax request is being sent synchronously, the browser will be locked up immediately before it has time to render the spinner. When it's done, it will immediately hide the spinner, thus causing it to not display at all. The alert gave the browser enough time to render the spinner before sending the ajax request.

Remove `async: false`